# Having trouble with simple arithmetic in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic

So, this is the logic I am trying to implement:

```
date120 = date5;
date90 = min(date90,date120);
date60 = min(date60, date90, date120);
date30 = min(date30,date60,date90,date120);
```

where the min function finds the lowest POSITIVE integer.

And here is how I am looping it:

```
 if(strStatus != "5" && date5 >= 0)
{
    date120 = date5;
    COUT<<"date30 is "<<date30<<" and date60 is "<<date60<<" and date120 is "<<date5<<" and date90 is "<<date90<<ENDL;
    if((date120 < date90) && (date120 >= 0))
    {
        date90 = date120;
        COUT<<"and date90 is "<<date90<<ENDL;
        if((date90 < date60) && (date90 >= 0))
        {
            date60 = date90;
            COUT<<"and date60 is "<<date60<<ENDL;
            if((date60 < date30) && (date60 >= 0))
            {
                date30 = date60;
                COUT<<"and date30 is "<<date30<<ENDL;
            }
        }
        if((date60 < date30) && (date60 >= 0))
            date30 = date60;
    }
    if((date90 < date60) && (date90 >= 0))
    {
        date60 = date90;
        COUT<<"and date60 is "<<date60<<ENDL;
        if((date60 < date30) && (date60 >= 0))
            date30 = date60;
    }
    if((date60 < date30) && (date60 >= 0))
    {
        date30 = date60;
        COUT<<"and date30 is "<<date30<<ENDL;
    }
    COUT<<"Because there was a 5 and date30 is "<<date30<<" and date60 is "<<date60<<ENDL;
}
```

And the output in the logs looks like :

```
date30 is -1 and date60 is -1 and date120 is 15 and date90 is -1
Because there was a 5 and date30 is -1 and date60 is -1
```

Am I doing something wrong with my logic? Am I missing something logic wise? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: There are no 'else' cases in your code, are you sure that the control flow is correct? This code is really hard to analyse because there's a lot of branches and it isn't obvious how your data flows between them. I'd say you should restructure the code; you have a good way to describe how it SHOULD work so just translate it word by word: define a "positiveMin" function and continue from there.

Comment: What is `COUT` and `ENDL`? Do you mean `std::cout` and `std::endl`?

Comment: yes, they are the same std::cout and std::endl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in regards to @Rob's anwer, he needs to restrict min to the lowest **positive** integer, so I suggest you implement a custom min function such as

```
int minpos( int x, int y ) {
    return x <= 0 ? y : ( y <= 0 ? x : std::min( x, y ) );
}
```

and then use what @Rob suggests:

```
date120 = date5;
date90 = minpos( date90, date120 );
...
```

Don't forget to #include <algorithm>

I assume if both numbers are non-positive it doesn't matter which one is returned.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need a `min` function with the behavior you described:

```
// If only one of a,b is non-negative, return it.
// if both of a,b are non-negative, return the lesser
// untested
int myMin(int a, int b) {
  if(b < 0)
    return a;
  if(a < 0)
    return b;
  if(b < a)
    return b;
  return a;
}
```

Then your code becomes trivial:

```
// untested
date120 = date5;
date90 = myMin(date90, date120);
date60 = myMin(date60, date90);
date30 = myMin(date30, date60);
```

Answer (score 1):

among other things, your code won't do anything because date90 is -1 so less than date120. 
So the first if fails to do anything, and then there's nothing for the rest of them to do.

The other if statements all have the same problem as the first.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is equivalent to:

```
date120 = date5;
date90 = min(date90, date120);
date60 = min(date60, date90);
date30 = min(date30, date60);
```

I assume from your code (`>= 0`) you really meant non-negative, not positive.

I would write it like this I think:

```
template <typename T>
T min_non_negative(T t1, T t2)
{
    return(std::min(t1 >= 0 ? t1 : t2, t2 >= 0 ? t2 : t1));  // Let the compiler do this in the best way for my platform.
}

date120 = date5;
date90 = min_non_negative(date90, date120);
date60 = min_non_negative(date60, date90);
date30 = min_non_negative(date30, date60);
```